# Insert Facebook button into header

Tags: headers, facebook, header-image

I am trying to add a Facebook button to the center of my header image. I have tried adding a link to my header.php on different sections, but it either displays the button above or beneath the logo, instead of inside the image. Any suggestions on where I should insert it?

Website: http://www.gelnagels-gina.be

Image: http://www.gelnagels-gina.be/wp-content/themes/optimizer/facebook.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `position: absolute` to your Facebook button.

**Header.php**

```
<div class="logo"> 
 <a class="logoimga" title="Gelnagels Gina" href="http://www.gelnagels-gina.be/">
   <img src="http://www.gelnagels-gina.be/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Gina4.png">
 </a>
 <a class="header-img-1" title="Facebook-header" href="#">
   <img src="http://www.gelnagels-gina.be/wp-content/themes/optimizer/facebook.png">
</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header-img-1 {
    left: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Works like a charm. It seems I was also pasting code in the wrong spot ...